# Expand a UITableViewCell to show an additional text label when selected

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

As the question states, I'm trying to expand a UITableViewCell when the user selects it in order to show additional information within that cell. I've looked at similarly related questions on here, and have kinda gotten it to work. The app doesn't crash, and the cells do expand, but I keep getting constraint layout errors in my console. I'm almost positive that I'm getting these errors because when a UITableViewCell has not been selected it is not tall enough to contain additional label, even though the label is hidden until the cell is selected. If someone has a suggestion, or another way I can accomplish the functionality, I would really appreciate the help. Thanks!

**The Custom Cell I'm Trying to Expand**

```
class ListTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var wordLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var definitionLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        self.definitionLabel.hidden = true
    }
}
```

**UITableView Code to Expand a UITableViewCell when selected**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ListTableViewCell

    if cell.definitionLabel.hidden == true {
        cell.definitionLabel.hidden = false         
    } else {
        cell.definitionLabel.hidden = true
    }

    currentRow = indexPath.row
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if currentRow == indexPath.row {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    } else {
        return 55.0
    }
}
```

Comment: call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` to reload the height of the cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On selection you could call reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: this should update the size of this cell. [See Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:)